# Observe Data from Room using View model in Kotlin

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I am creating a social media app and I am following `MVVM` Pattern
I am stuck at `observing` data from DB . As far I know is the `Dao` methods have to be executed on the background `thread`. But I am not able to implement `viewmodel` from `Repository` Class.I will paste the code ,Can anyone give me some help?

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface FeedDao{

//Post feed item
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(feed:Feed):Long

//Update feed item
@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun update(feed: Feed):Int

//Get feed from user friend's
@Query("SELECT * from feed")
fun getAllFeed():LiveData<List<Feed>>
}
```

**Repository**

```
class FeedRepository private constructor(private val feedDao: FeedDao) {

companion object {
    @Volatile private var instance:FeedRepository? = null
    private val apiClient = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(UserClient::class.java)
    fun getInstance(feedDao: FeedDao)= instance?: synchronized(this){
      instance ?: FeedRepository(feedDao).also { instance=it }
     }
}


private fun getFeedResponse() {

    //TODO:Check to change parameter values after adding Paging Functionality
    val call: Call<List<Feed>> = apiClient.getFeed(20, 0)
    call.enqueue(object :Callback<List<Feed>>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Feed>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.e("FeedRepository","Feed Callback Failure")
            Timber.d(t?.message)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Feed>>?, response: Response<List<Feed>>?) {
            if(response!!.isSuccessful){
                Timber.i("Successful Response -> Adding to DB")
                addResponseTODB(response.body()!!)
            }else{
                when(response.code()){
                    400 -> Timber.d("Not Found 400")
                    500 -> Timber.d("Not logged in or Server broken")
                }

            }

        }
    })
}

private fun addResponseTODB(items:List<Feed>){
    Timber.d("Response --> DB Started")
    object :  AsyncTask<List<Feed>,Void,Boolean>(){
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: List<Feed>?): Boolean {
            var needsUpdate:Boolean = false
            for(item in params[0]!!.iterator()){
                var inserted = feedDao.insert(item)
                if(inserted.equals(-1)){
                    var updated = feedDao.update(item)
                    if(updated > 0){
                        needsUpdate = true
                    }
                }else{
                    needsUpdate = true
                }
            }
            return needsUpdate
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean?) {
            if (result!!){
                loadFromDB()
            }
        }

    }.execute(items)
}


private fun loadFromDB(){
    Timber.d("loadFromDB")

    object :AsyncTask<Void,Void,LiveData<List<Feed>>>(){
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): LiveData<List<Feed>>? {
            return feedDao.getAllFeed()
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: LiveData<List<Feed>>?) {

        }
    }.execute()
}


public fun fetchFeed(){
    Timber.d("fetchFeed")
    loadFromDB()
    getFeedResponse()
}

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class FeedViewModel private constructor(private val 
feedDao:FeedDao):ViewModel(){
// TODO: Implement the ViewModel

private val feedRepository= FeedRepository.getInstance(feedDao)
public val feed = MediatorLiveData<List<Feed>>()
val value = MutableLiveData<Int>()
init {
        feed.addSource(feed,feed::setValue)
}

companion object {
    private const val NO_FEED = -1
}

fun getFeedLD() = feed

}
```

Comment: Can you once check this link.I just google it with your issue and I found this.I think this link can help you so far for implementing the ViewModel & Repository class.https://medium.com/rocknnull/exploring-kotlin-using-android-architecture-components-and-vice-versa-aa16e600041a

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to insert all `Feed` objects one by one in the `Database`. You can create a method inside `FeedDao` which to insert `List<Feed>`

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(feed: List<Feed>):Long
```

Than, it is not necessary to call `loadFromDB()` inside the `onPostExecute()` method, because your `fun getAllFeed(): LiveData<List<Feed>>()` method from `@FeedDao` returns `LiveData` and you can add `Observer` to it and every time when the data inside the Database is changes the `Observer` will be triggered.

And for your Network/Database requests you always can use `NetworkBoundResource` https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt

Hope I helped somehow :)